# How to load seed_fu fixtures before testing with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, seed

I'm trying to setup rspec for testing in my rails application. I have created some sample test and executed `rake rspec --trace`.

In output I see this messages

```
** Invoke spec:models (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
```

Schema gets loaded and then rake task breaks, because I'm trying to use some values from database in one of files in initializers directory. Normally those records are in the database, they are all present in seed_fu files in db/fixtures directory.

I'm looking a way to execute this files after `db:schema:load`. Somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you can access the seeder directly with a simple call to `SeedFu.seed`.

This has the advantage of ensuring seeds run in the proper order, and if you need to, you can pass arguments for specific fixture paths or filtering options - I could see using a specific path useful for test-only fixtures, for instance.

Here's the seed-fu method:

```
# Load seed data from files
# @param [Array] fixture_paths The paths to look for seed files in
# @param [Regexp] filter If given, only filenames matching this expression will be loaded
def self.seed(fixture_paths = SeedFu.fixture_paths, filter = nil)
  Runner.new(fixture_paths, filter).run
end
```

I have no idea if this method is meant to be used publicly, but for now at least it seems to work well for my uses.

Comment: I should also mention, the `SeedFu.seed` call makes sense within a before(:suite) call to maximize value of seeds while minimizing DB traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with acceptable but not ideal solution. I've removed reference to database from initailizers file and replaced it with simple integer assignment. To load my seeds I added this line in `spec_helper.rb`

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("db/fixtures/*.rb")].each {|file| load file }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this in rspec tests before start:

```
`rake db:seed_fu`
```

or

```
`rake db:seed_fu FILTER=locales`
```

and after tests

```
`rake db:reset`
```

Note the magic quotes - ``

Example:

```
describe "POST /v1/products" do
  before(:all) do
    `rake db:seed_fu FILTER=4_locales`
  end

  after(:all) do
    `rake db:reset`
  end

  ...
end
```